# Namespaces not being recognized

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, namespaces

I have the following class

```
namespace _Scripts.EnemyStuff
{
    public class Enemy : MonoBehaviour, IDamagable
    {
    }
}
```

And then when I try to use the class `Enemy` I need to specify that it comes from `_Scripts.EnemyStuff` even if they share the same parent.

The following code doesn't detect the `Enemy` class. I need to specify `EnemyStuff.Enemy` in order to make it work.

```
namespace _Scripts.Managers
{
    public class EnemyManager : MonoBehaviour
    {
        public Enemy firstEnemyGO;
    }
}
```

Why is this happening? Also, why it doesn't work if I use

```
using Enemy = _Scripts.EnemyStuff.Enemy;
```

Comment: just add a `using _Scripts.EnemyStuff;` to the top of your `EnemeyManager`-script.

Comment: what do you mean by "even if they share the same parent."?

Comment: event adding using_Scripts.EnemyStuff doesn't work, for some reason the compiler is detecting a duplicated of this class even if only 1 exists

Comment: I mean that even if I put both clases on the same namespace _Scripts, it is not detecting it correctly

Comment: Do you have two classes with the name `Enemy`?

Comment: C# finds a class in a parent namespace, but not in a sibling namespace. Did you place `using Enemy = _Scripts.EnemyStuff.Enemy;` in the Managers script?

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Currently all we can do is *guessing*, as we don't have all required information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general you always have to exactly define which type you are referring to. I would rather see it the other way round and there are certain cases where c# already "knows" so you can omit namespaces or parts of them. Among those e.g.

- If you have a `using XYNamespace;` you can now omit `XYNamespace.` when referring to types within it.
- If your type is in the **same** namespace or a **subnamesapce** of it

See also [namespaces](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/namespaces)

> share the same parent

They do not really! Your namespace hierarchy looks like

```
_Scripts
|-- EnemyStuff
|   |-- Enemy
|
|-- Managers
    |-- EnemyManager
```

c# looks for the type recursive up in the parent path (`_Scripts.Managers.XY` or `_Scripts.XY`) bu doesn't bubble back down all possible sibling namespaces.

So yes in this structure you will need to provided the namespace and use e.g.

```
public EnemyStuff.Enemy firstEnemyGO;
```

the `EnemyStuff` actually **can** be found looking in the common parent namespace `_Scripts` so you can omit the `_Scripts.`

---

Either

```
using System;
using UnityEngine;
using Enemy = _Scripts.EnemyStuff.Enemy;

namespace _Scripts.Managers
{
    public class EnemyManager : MonoBehaviour
    {
        public Enemy firstEnemyGO;
    }
}
```

or

```
using System;
using UnityEngine;

namespace _Scripts.Managers
{
    using Enemy = EnemyStuff.Enemy;
    
    public class EnemyManager : MonoBehaviour
    {
        public Enemy firstEnemyGO;
    }
}
```

or

```
using System;
using UnityEngine;

namespace _Scripts.Managers
{
    public class EnemyManager : MonoBehaviour
    {
        public EnemyStuff.Enemy firstEnemyGO;
    }
}
```

work perfectly fine for me